# What is lib or way scroll horizontal list item with 2 row

Tags: android

I want display list data with 2 row, and can scroll horizontal like this:
[image]

I try using Gridview but can not do it.What is Lib or way can help me? 
Please suggest for me, thank so much!

Comment: You can use `Recyclerview` with `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: it support for one row, i cant custom for two row.
I want can scroll with position like this:
`1 3 5 7....
2 4 6 8.....`

Comment: Then a `LinearLayoutManager with Horizontal Scroll enabled` with a view contains `two vertical layouts` might be the solution.

Comment: final GridLayoutManager mng_layout = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
It only set for column , i cant set for row.
I want only 2 row and can Horizontal croll